# PQexecParams() returning ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

If fr_dt is empty - PQresultErrorMessage() return "ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: """
My c code:

```
    string new_data = "some new data";
    string fr_dt = obj.getDate();

    const char *c_new_data = new_data.c_str();
    const char *c_fr_dt = fr_dt.c_str();
  
    const char* ins_data_com = "select * from ins_data($1,$2);
    int nParams = 2;
    const char *const paramValues[] = {c_new_data,c_fr_dt};
    const int paramLengths[] = {sizeof(c_new_data),sizeof(c_fr_dt)};
    const int paramFormats[] = {0,0};
    int resultFormat = 0;
    
    PGresult res_com = PQexecParams(conn,ins_data_com, 
                       nParams, NULL, paramValues, paramLengths, paramFormats, resultFormat);
```

and pgsql code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ins_data(in_data text, in_date date)
        RETURNS int
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
        AS $function$
        DECLARE n_id int;
    BEGIN
        WITH cte AS (
        INSERT INTO public.my_table
        (new_data, time_in)
        VALUES(in_data, coalesce(in_date::timestamp,current_timestamp))
        RETURNING id AS new_id
        )
        SELECT new_id INTO n_id FROM cte;
        RETURN n_id;
    END;
        $function$
        ;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Error message is straight forward you are trying to enter an empty string as a `date` and that is not allowed: `select ''::date; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""`. You need to make sure that the value is properly formatted date string or date type.

Comment: I added if (fr_dt.empty()){fr_dt = "NULL"}, but its come to sql as string ('NULL')

Comment: Someone who is a C programmer is going to have to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
  const char *с_fr_dt = NULL;
            if (!fr_dt.empty()) {
              с_fr_dt = fr_dt.c_str();
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change all of the empty date with 1970-01-01, and then change the data type of that column to date (if input null it will automatically add 1970-01-01).